# What is the purpose of integration tests?

Tags: orm, repository, integration-testing

Let's suppose we designed data access layer as repository pattern with nhibernate support.

What I wonder is; while testing a repository what are we really testing??

Are we testing Orm does it's job right or the database can run queries as expected?

If I have a repository like; OrderRepository, why should i test Save,Update,FindbyId methods?

I think the only thing needs to be tested is Orm mappings the other things don't make sense to me.

Because Orms like Nhibernate,Entity Framework are mature frameworks so; why would I have to worry about that "context.Add()" or "session.Save()" working or not if mappings done right?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible that there may be no (or very little) return on that investment.  Testing is like that sometimes.

It depends on how you define the value of the testing.  For some, there's inherent value in chasing that elusive 100% coverage.  If there's time to build those tests, great.  100% coverage is a nice warm fuzzy to have.  But, as you imply, not all of the tests which brought one there are truly meaningful.  Often the primary value in that case is the bragging rights of the 100% coverage metric.  (Perhaps a picky client wants to see that number on a report somewhere, for example.)

Or perhaps the integration tests stand as a valuable tool outside the context of the ORM or whatever other tools may be used to build the DAL.  If you consider the DAL as a black box from the perspective of a technical-but-non-developer resource, they may want a tool which can test *any* implementation of the DAL interface and ensure, end to end, that the implementation works in a live environment when properly configured.

Perhaps the entire integration test is really not testing the *code* per se, but from their perspective is testing that the database and application are mutually properly configured and talking to each other.  *That* person doesn't care about ORMs or mappings, they care that a couple of separate system components on a UML diagram are working together to the extent of the system's specifications.  Whether that component uses an ORM, uses manual SQL, or uses magical pixie dust makes no difference to that test.

It really comes down to which role on the team wants the test and what they're actually trying to test/validate.